# Efficiency of MP1496 Synchronous Step-Down Converter at 1mA

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, low-power, step-down

I'm curious of what efficiency I can expect from MP1496 Synchronous Step-Down Converter (https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/mp1496.html) at 1mA, assuming 12V in and 3.3V out. Datasheet doesn't show values for small currents:

[image]

How badly this curve drops? I'm not looking for exact numbers, unless you have them. Otherwise, just a guesstimate will do.

Answer (score 3):

Neglecting the dissipation across the switching elements, inductor, and feedback resistors, the total dissipation will not be much higher than that in quiescent.

Supply current at quiescent is given as 1mA maximum. So we can approximate the dissipation of the device as something around 12-15mW. So, at 1mA load current, I'd expect an efficiency of around 20-25 percent.

Answer (score 1):

It drops to a such low value that it makes no sense to use it, if the efficiency is your concern.

Further you have to look if it can work in DCM mode, what is the minimum conducting time - then you will be able to calculate the max. output ripple.

Ckeck if the lower switch is disabled at low output current - if not you'll get reverse current and damage.

There are other more important things to look if you plan to use a synchronous buck at low or even zero current.